# Access Method return Array

Tags: java

I have a problem about how to access method with return array type. This is my code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int value = 5;
    for(int i=0; i<value; i++){
        System.out.println((i+1)+ "=" + Arrays.toString(Arr(value)));
    }
}

private static int[] Arr(int n){
    int[] x = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        x[i] = i+1;
    }
    return x;
}
```

The code result always print [1,2,3,4,5] for 5 times. 
My question is how to access specific array number, for example how to access arr[1] which is contain 2 or arr[2] which is contain 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you're creating a new array *every time you go through the loop*. This is very slow and wasteful, especially if you only want to print out one value each time.

To get your code as it stands just to print out a single value, you'd do this:

```
int value = 5;
for(int i=0; i<value; i++){
    System.out.println((i+1)+ "=" + Arr(value)[i]);
}
```

But as I say, because you call `Arr` each time, this will be very inefficient. What you really want to do is to create the array once, and then loop through it:

```
int value = 5;
int[] array = Arr(value);
for(int i=0; i<value; i++){
    System.out.println((i+1)+ "=" + array[i]);
}
```

If you want to see for yourself what the effect of this change is, try setting `value` to 10000000 or more, and you should notice the first one gradually slow down the longer it runs.

Set it going and notice how fast it starts. Then go and make a drink, and see if it's still running fast when you get back. (If it's finished when you get back, set the value even higher.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
System.out.println((i+1)+ "=" + Arr(value)[i]);
```

You are getting int array, so if you have index, then you could just access it like above. It's equivalent of

```
int[] array = Arr(value);
System.out.println((i+1)+ "=" + array[i]);
```

Two points worth noting:

- You method name should start with small case.
- You are calling method in a loop. Bring it out of loop and call it just once to speed up your code execution.

Answer (score 1):

You should call the method once, and access elements of the returned array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int value = 5;
    int[] result = Arr(value);
    for(int i=0; i<value; i++){
        System.out.println((i+1)+ "=" + result[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print each element one by one

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int value = 5;
    int[] output=Arr(value);
    for(int i=0; i<value; i++){
        System.out.println((i+1)+ "=" + output[i]);
    }
}

private static int[] Arr(int n){
    int[] x = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        x[i] = i+1;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Upvoted only because you provide the code that *fix* the issue. Still, you should explain how this code fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The function returns an array, from which you can access elements like `Arr(value)[index]`. following is an example:

```
System.out.println((i+1)+ "=" + Arrays.toString(Arr(value)[i]));
```

You can also use a temp array in this case:

```
int[] temp = Arr(value);
System.out.println((i+1)+ "=" + temp[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
System.out.println((i+1)+ "=" + Arr(value)[i]);
```

Simple and i hope it'd help.

- when you use + with string ("="), so it already converted element of Array of Int to String.

Answer (score 0):

You call the function by wrong params.

you can call like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int value = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
        System.out.println((i + 1) + "=" + Arrays.toString(Arr(i + 1)));
    }
}
```